# Edit user in Jenkins via groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, user-management

I am wondering if I can change password, username, email in Jenkins user. Because I am able to create user via groovy script like this:

```
import hudson.model.*

def user = instance.securityRealm.createAccount(userId, password)
user.addProperty(new Mailer.UserProperty(email));
instance.save()
```

Jenkins interface allows me to manage user credentials, but script which allow to change **password/email/username** would be very helpfull. I didnt find examples.

I tried many times with script like this, but It didnt work

```
import hudson.model.*

User user = User.getAll().get(1)
user.setProperty(newPassword)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple code that works :

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.security.*
import hudson.tasks.Mailer

def env = System.getenv()

def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
if(!(jenkins.getSecurityRealm() instanceof HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm))
    jenkins.setSecurityRealm(new HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm(false))

if(!(jenkins.getAuthorizationStrategy() instanceof GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy))
    jenkins.setAuthorizationStrategy(new GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy())

// update admin Jenkins user account
def user = jenkins.getSecurityRealm().getUser('admin')
email= 'jenkins-admin@gmail.com'
user.addProperty(new Mailer.UserProperty(email));
```

Answer (score 0):

For Jenkins Jenkins 2.361.1, I have used such Jenkins groovy script to update user's password:

```
User.getById("userName",false).addProperty(hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm.Details.fromPlainPassword("new-password"));
```

You can also easily run it from bash script or similar, given $USERNAME and $PASSWORD are set:

```
echo "script=User.getById(\"$USERNAME\",false).addProperty(hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm.Details.fromPlainPassword(\"$PASSWORD\"));" | \
curl -d @- --user admin:access_token http://<ip>:8080/scriptText
```